# Audit fields(CreatedBy, UpdatedBy) in tables. Is it good idea?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, database-design

I was working with one product where almost every table had those columns. As developers we constantly had to join to Users table to get Id of who created record and it's just a mess in a code.

I'm designing new product and thinking about this again. Does it have to be like this? Obviously, it is good to know who created record and when. But having 300+ tables reference same User table doesn't seem to be very good..

How do you handle things like this? Should I create CreatedBy column only on major entities where it's most likely needed on UI and than deal with joining? Or should I go and put it everywhere? Or maybe have another "Audit" table where I store all this and look it up only on demand(not every time entity displayed on UI)

I'm just worrying about performance aspect where every UI query will hit User table..

EDIT: This is going to be SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Comment: Why do you think that "having 300+ tables reference same User table doesn't seem to be very good"? What are you basing this on?

Comment: Can you please specify the minimum version of SQL Server you need to support. As you can see, potential suggestions may not be appropriate for your version. It is always a good idea to mention and/or tag the question with the right version to save people time and effort. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron: I added server version

Comment: @Oded Well, client uses EntityFramework so it will be 
1. Messy on schema side - lot's of extra dependencies
2. Messy on data retreival side. Joins every time entity retreived

Comment: The use of EF is very relevant to the question. Why didn't you add this detail to it? The more relevant information (why you don't want to do certain things, what you are trying to achieve etc) you add to you question, the better the answers.

Comment: It seems to me that you just need to look up the current user's id number once, when usage starts, and just remember it until that user logs off or goes out of session (or whatever). What am I missing?

Comment: @Catcall For storing records - yes. But for retreiving I have to remember ALL users or join every time I retreive record.

Comment: @katit: If you store the unique username instead of an id number, you don't need a join to get the username. (But you still need a join to get the real name associated with the unique username.)

Comment: @Catcall. I do need a join because storing ID is not right way to do it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that approach is that you only know who created the row and who changed the row *last*. What if the last person to update the row was correcting the previous updater's mistake?

If you're interested in doing full auditing for compliance or accountability reasons, you should probably look into [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx). You can dictate which tables you're auditing, can change those on the fly without having to mess with your schema, and you can write queries against this data specifically instead of mixing the auditing logic with your normal application query logic (never mind widening every row of the table itself). This will also allow you to audit `SELECT` queries, which other potential solutions (triggers, CDC, Change Tracking - all of which are either more work or not complete for true auditing purposes) won't let you do that.

Comment: Audit was introduced in SQL Server 2008 and is not available on previous versions.

Comment: @Oded To be fair, the OP didn't specify what version of SQL Server they are using (pre-2008 would also discount CDC and Change Tracking). While not universal, it seems reasonable to assume that the average user is on 2008 or above, or if they have to move to Enterprise to take advantage of Enterprise features, such an upgrade would just be part of the move.

Comment: I know. I was trying to add info to the answer, not to criticize it.

Comment: @Oded yep, I wasn't trying to sound defensive. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron I quickly looked how SQL Server audit works so maybe I didn't get it completely but what I see is that it may not work with single login? This is web application, everything comes in via single connection string.

Comment: How does your application pass the real username now? Manually into every single stored procedure?

Comment: We use entity framework without stored procedures. But yes, we associate User with every entity we save (set UserKey)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an older post, but one way to avoid the lookup on the user table is to de-normalize the audit fields.

So instead of a userid in the CreatedBy field you insert a username itself.  This will allow for a review of the table without the user look and also allow for any changes in your user table not reflect in the audit fields.  Such as deleted users.

I usually add  the following to the end of a table

```
IsDeleted bit default 0
CreatedBy varchar(20)
CreatedOn datetime2 default getdate()
UpdatedBy varchar(20)
UpdatedOn datetime2 default getdate()
```